# JDK 1.5 Properties load with unicode characters

Tags: java, unicode, java-5

JDK 1.5 Properties [load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) method only gets InputStream while JDK 1.6+ [load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) method also gets also Reader. When a string with Unicode characters is loaded to a properties object on JDK 1.6+ with load(reader), there is no problem. But on JDK 1.5 there is only load(InputStream) method; when loaded to properties unicode characters are not correctly loaded.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
Reader reader = null;
try {
        bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(someStringWithUnicodeChars.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        reader = new InputStreamReader(bis, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

props.load(reader); // This reads unicode characters correctly on JDK 1.6+

// There is no props.load(reader) method on JDK 1.5, so below method is used
props.load(bis);
// but Unicode characters are not loaded correctly.
```

How can I load following example string with unicode characters to properties object.

```
key1=test İ Ş Ğ
key2=ÇÇÇÇ
```

Comment: Generally you'd need to use unicode escapes in the properties file for them to load correctly with an `InputStream` (i.e. \u00FF type of substitution).

Answer (score 1):

From the 1.5 javadoc "The stream is assumed to be using the ISO 8859-1 character encoding"
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29)

Try this:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(someStringWithUnicodeChars.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
```

Comment: This gives compilation error. charset cannot be used in getBytes.

Answer (score 0):

therefor in the JDK exists the tool native2ascii[.exe].

```
1) create the properties file as UTF-8, name it for example: sample.native
2) convert the native properties file to Unicode escape sequences: native2ascii prop.native > prop.properties
3) load and process the properties file

// example: you will see the right UTF-8 characters only if your console suppert UTF-8
class PropsFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sample.properties")) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(fis);
            for (String name : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
                System.out.println(name + "=" + props.getProperty(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```